# Cache a set of strings with LRU eviction policy in Java

Tags: java, caching, memory, guava

I am trying to create a cache for a set of Strings with LRU eviction policy in this way.

```
private static final Boolean PLACEHOLDER = true;
LoadingCache<String, Boolean> scannedIDsCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean load(String key) throws Exception {
                return PLACEHOLDER;
            }
        });
```

I think I am saving space using only one object as the value for all the elements, am I correct? Do you know any other space efficient way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you are not saving space.

When a JVM* [autoboxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) a `boolean` it calls [`Boolean.valueOf(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)) which returns either [`Boolean.TRUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TRUE) or [`Boolean.FALSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#FALSE) which are `static final Boolean` fields. It does not create a new [`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) instance. As such, the `PLACEHOLDER` you've defined is in fact a reference to `Boolean.TRUE` and is redundant.

Furthermore, I would not use Guava's `Cache` for an LRU unless I am willing to accept the fact that "the cache may evict an entry because it hasn't been used recently *or very often*" ([CacheBuilder.maximumSize(long)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#maximumSize-long-), *emphasis* added).

If you want a straight-up LRU you can use [`Collections.newSetFromMap(Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)) with [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
Set<String> cache = Collections.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
    }
});
```

Where you define `MAX_ENTRIES`.

---

*Note: Theoretically there could be some JVM implementation(s) out there that don't call `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)` (or something similar) at runtime when autoboxing `boolean` primitives but if such an implementation exists I am fairly confident you are not using it and that very few if any individuals are. From [`Boolean(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean(boolean)):

> **Note: It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Unless a *new* instance is required, the static factory [`valueOf(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)) is generally a better choice. It is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So, I think I am wasting space for the reference PLACEHOLDER. It's ok for me to Guava's cache. Instead of using `true` or `false`, can I save more space with any other object type?

Comment: @theeminence Guava Cache is already pretty space minimal. I am not aware of any ways to reduce storage further.